# Python requests - submit form via POST request for site with recaptcha

Tags: python, forms, web-scraping, postman, recaptcha

### BACKGROUND

1. I'm trying to automate form submission for a site.
2. I'm trying to access the quote given for the form data.
3. The site is protected by reCAPTCHA. - I’ve seen the token being sent in network devtools

### QUESTION / HELP

I want to know if it is possible to automate submitting the form; and how; WITHOUT a browser instance tool like Selenium. I have all the form data and headers from the forms POST request from devtools

### WHAT I'VE TRIED

I manually filled the form with dummy values and watched the devtools network tab on clicking "submit". I found the POST request and copied the request headers and form body and pasted into POSTMAN - I never get to the second page (with the quote) however in my POSTMAN trials

### WHY

For anyone wondering why I really badly want to do this, I'm trying to create a car insrance quote aggregator tool for my country as there currently isn't one and filling forms is a pain. So I want to create this service (Only ~20 providers.

Comment: Can you share the website you're trying this on?

Comment: @Hamza Rana https://secure.ami.co.nz/css/car/step1

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the problem is that reCAPTCHA. But as you know, preventing robots is exactly the task of reCAPTCHA.

Comment: @Sraw if you fill the site with dummy info it doesn’t ask you to fill out a captcha or anything, but I can see when I click submit a token is POSTED. Is there anyway to emulate this in code?

Comment: It is how the new reCAPTCHA works, it doesn't require you to fill out a captcha unless you behave like a robot. I mean, it uses AI to decide if you are a human first, using your action behaviors, such as how do you type the words, how do you move the mouse or something I don't really know the details. But it just won't let you go if you are really a robot. Well, for me, I would never imagine that I can beat one of the biggest companies in the world.

Comment: @Sraw using Selenium I can submit the site, and that definitely acts like a bot

Comment: Sraw is right 100%. The reCaptchas are there to prevent you from crawling their websites. The tokens will be changing on each quote submission according to your transaction on the website. 
I would go on this website with Selenium, by which I can click on random stuff, scroll etc.

Comment: Thanks - so the only way is with a browser instance tool like Selenium?

Comment: Based on my understanding, for example, it won't prevent you to use Selenium for the first time(or maybe first a few times) even you act like a bot. But it will ban you if you crawl multiple times. The idea of the new reCAPTCHA is to preventing robots with the least influence on normal customers. They use a mechanism called "reputation" for every IP, your action will influence your reputation. If you keep acting like a bot, you will have a low reputation which causes you to be banned. You can take a look at the document: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3